# classroom time booking system database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database

I'm working in a classroom booking system for a university use and I want to ask which approach is better in designing the database for time booking
is it using slots ( each slot is half an hour and will be predefined for example 7-7:30 is slot 1) ? or time period (for example 2-4:30) ?

Below are the tables and just their primary keys:

```
SLOTS

TeacherID 
ClassroomID 
Slot 
Date
```

so same teacher can book different rooms in the same day with different slots.

slot Advantages:
it's easier approach for me since I'm a beginner in C#.net

slot Disadvantages:
It will need a huge memory and will make trillions of records

```
PERIODS
BookingID 
Timeperiod
```

Period Advantages:
it's DIFFICULT approach for me since I'm a beginner in C#.net

Period Disadvantages:
It will need a huge memory and will make trillions of records

SO knowing that ,, what do you think !!? 
and if any one suggested the period approach can you help in how to program it?

Comment: better to add a submission date, something like, this Assignment should be submitted on or before `20/04/2016`

Comment: it's a system for booking classrooms only ! and I'm giving you only the PKs
I have my own other columns

Comment: First ask yourself if there is a free or almost free system that is already written that will do this for you.... unless part of the project is actually building a system like this as opposed to sourcing a pre built one.

Comment: trillions of records? At worst, 100 rooms fully booked in half hour slots for 12 hours a day for 10 years = 24 slots X 365 days X 100 rooms X 10 years = 5 million records which isn't much for a database. That's a worst case. Realistically you're more likely to end up with more like 500,000 records after ten years. I suggest you do not 'bake in' half hour bookings into your system. It'll be a problem. A booking record should have the person booking it, the room, the start datetime and the end datetime. Don't complicate it.

Comment: An example of a "free" system might be something on Office 365